# When using the Windows SDK 7.1 Command Prompt, how do I change the build environment without losing the nmake command?

Tags: nmake, winapi

I just installed the Windows 7.1 SDK and launched the SDK Command Prompt. If I type `nmake`, I am greeted with this message:

```
Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 10.00.30319.01
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

NMAKE : fatal error U1064: MAKEFILE not found and no target specified
Stop.
```

This is what I expect. However, I want to target Windows x64, so I type: `setenv /x64`. Then if I run `nmake`, I get an error:

```
'nmake' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Why am I getting this error? What am I doing wrong? I am using Windows 8 Consumer Preview 32-bit on my machine.

---

**Edit:** here is a diff of the `PATH` environment variable before and after:
http://diffchecker.com/9jdFi5d

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems Microsoft forgot to place an `nmake.exe` binary in the x86_amd64 directory (the others all have it). I suggest copying the `nmake.exe` in the main `Bin` directory to the ´Bin/x86_amd64` directory.